# XSLT: How to generate id attribute of HTML whose value is constant regardless of change of source XML and also proper as a part of URL

Tags: url, xslt

I use XSLT 1.0 to transform source XML file to HTML document. In source file there are `section` elements.

```
<section name="Name of this section">
    ...
</section>
```

And it is transformed to HTML as following (`h2` may change to `h3`, `h4`, etc. according to the level of nesting).

```
<h2 id="...">Name of this section</h2>
```

`id` attribute is used to reference this section from other HTML document.

```
<a href="https://www.example.org/document.html#(valude of id attribute)">Link to the section</a>
```

Currently `geterate-id` function is used to generate the value of `id` attribute. But it may change when structure of source XML file is changed. And it results in breakage of link from other HTML document. So I would like to make value of `id` attribute constant even if structure of source file is changed.

At first I considered using the value of `name` attribute. But sometimes it includes characters that is improper as a part of URL (space, question mark, non-ASCII UTF-8 characters, etc.). So it can't be used.

Next I considered adding `id` attribute to `section` element of source XML file and using it as is in HTML file. It surely provide proper value but adding it to all `section` element in source file is bothersome. So I would like to think of it as last resort.

Then is there any way to generete the value of `id` attribute that is constant regardless of change of source file and also proper as a part of URL?

Comment: So how/where/when do you generate the id in the link of the other document? If your algorithm there works you need to apply the same one. Or generate both in the same code i.e. in XSLT 2 or 3 you can use `xsl:result-document` to generate separate documents with one transformation.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Unfortunately html documents referencing ours are maintained by other organization and out of our control. So it's impossible to apply our algorithm to their documents. This is why I'd like to make the value of 'id' attribute constant regardless of changes of source file.

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of documents referencing mine told me `encode-for-uri()` of XSLT 2.0 and `str:encode-uri()` of EXSLT. I use `xsltproc` of libxslt as processor and it supports EXSLT. So I decided to use `str:encode-uri(@name)` as value of `id` attribute. There are two drawbacks about it. At first it doesn't guarantee uniqueness. If there are multiple `section` elements with the same `name` attribute value in source XML file, then `id` value will be duplicated. The second point is that when the value of the `name` attribute changes, the `id` value also changes. However, in my case they don't really matter. The value of `name` attribute is unique within source file and seldom changed. So I can make `id` unique and almost constant enough for my case.